# Firmware updates for the Hyundai i30

Tags: hyundai, software

Recently I found out that my car (an Hyundai i30 Premium 1.0 T-GDI 2018 model) has an SD-card slot with the maps on there. I also found out that in the Hyundai media system there is a screen with the maps and firmware version. I've got atwo questions about the firmware?

1. Is it possible to download a firmware update somewhere (to install it on my car)?
2. Is it possible to see the changelog of the firmware somewhere? I would love to see what the updates fix/improve.

I searched for the firmware but could only find maps updates. And these updates weren't even on the official Hyundai website. I haven't found anything about firmware updates yet.

I am aware that a dealer can update the firmware, but I would like to try it out myself and I would love to know what is fixed/improved in newer versions.

The current firmware version that is displayed in the media system is: PD.EUR.0.5.222.170920.MICOM

Comment: There's DIY instructions to download software for the media system.  What makes you think your firmware isn't current?  Software (firmware) updates are available for specific systems on specific vehicles to improve bluetooth cellphone integration.  It's likely your 2018 is still current on firmware.

Comment: @SteveRacer How do you know there are DIY instructions. And do you know where these downloads are available? I haven't been able to find them. I'm not sure if there's an update. This is what I would like to find out.

Answer (score 0):

Here are the links (just some - you only need to Google "Hyundai Media System Firmware" and you will get dozens).

It doesn't seem your 2018 is affected, but FYI:

[Hyundai DIY Media System Software Updates](https://www.hyundaiusa.com/about-hyundai/news/Corporate_HYUNDAI_RELEASES_DOITYOURSELF_INSTALLATION_FOR_SMARTPHONE_INTEGRATIONS_ON_SEVERAL_EXISTING-20160526.aspx)

[Hyundai DIY Update Instructions pdf](http://Hyundai%20DIY%20pdf%20instructions)